# How to vertically align labels of a timeline at the bottom?

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can the labels in the following timeline be vertically aligned, so that it seems like they are all positioned on a base-line (so vertically aligned at the bottom)? For example, `\tau` and `\tau+1` are not vertically aligned at the bottom yet. So I want to use the placement at `\x` but the alignment in y-direction should be variable (not fixed at `-2mm` as at the moment)

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,x=0.5cm]
  \newcommand*{\mylabshift}{0.25}
  \draw[->] (-1,0) -- (27,0) node[below=2mm]{Time};
  \foreach \x in {0,1, 4,5, 9,10, 14, 19,20, 25}
  \draw(\x, 1.2mm) -- (\x, -1.2mm);
  \foreach \x/\what in {0/0, 1/1, 2.5/\dots, 4/\tau, 5+\mylabshift/\tau+1, 7.25/\dots, 9/t, 10+\mylabshift/t+1, 12.25/\dots, 14/t+h, 19-3*\mylabshift/T-h, 20+5*\mylabshift/T-h+1, 25/T}
  \node[below] at (\x,-2mm) {$\what$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### UPDATE

Define `timeline` environment and use `\event<*>[* or num or dimen]{num or dimen}{text}` to add event.

- First `*` will wrap the text with `$...$`.
- Optional argument is the x-coordinate of the tick, use `*` to set no tick. By default it is the same of the next argument.
- First mandatary argument is the x-coordiate of the event node.
- Second mandatary argument is the text.

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=1cm]{standalone}

\makeatletter
\newtoks\t@event@toka%
\newtoks\t@event@tokb%
\newif\ifevent@math%
\newif\ifevent@comp%
\newenvironment{timeline}[1][0.25]{%
  \begingroup%
  \let\event@tmpa\pgfutil@empty%
  \let\event@tmpb\pgfutil@empty%
  \let\event@tmpc\pgfutil@empty%
  \let\event@tmpd\pgfutil@empty%
  \edef\event@min{\the\maxdimen}%
  \edef\event@max{-\event@min}%
  \def\event{%
    \pgfutil@ifnextchar-%
      {\event@compfalse\event@}%
      {\event@comptrue\event@-}%
  }%
  \def\event@-{%
    \pgfutil@ifnextchar*%
      {\event@mathtrue\event@@}%
      {\event@mathfalse\event@@*}%
  }%
  \def\event@@*{%
    \pgfutil@ifnextchar[\event@@@{\@dblarg{\event@@@}}%
  }%
  \def\event@@@[##1]##2##3{%
    \edef\event@tmpb{%
      \noexpand\node[anchor=base] at (##2, -7mm)%
        {\ifevent@math$##3$\else##3\fi};%
      \ifx##1*\else%
        \noexpand\draw (##1, -1.2mm) -- (##1, 1.2mm);%
      \fi%
    }%
    \t@event@toka=\expandafter{\event@tmpa}%
    \t@event@tokb=\expandafter{\event@tmpb}%
    \edef\event@tmpa{\the\t@event@toka\the\t@event@tokb}%
    \ifx##1*\else%
      \event@set@axismax{##1}%
    \fi%
    \event@set@axismax{##2}%
  }%
  \def\event@set@axismax##1{%
    \tikz@checkunit{##1}%
    \iftikz@isdimension%
      \pgf@process{\pgfpoint{##1}{0pt}}%
    \else%
      \pgf@process{\pgfpointxy{##1}{0}}%
    \fi%
    \pgfmathparse{\the\pgf@x}%
    \let\event@cur\pgfmathresult%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\event@min{%
      \event@cur < \event@min ? \event@cur : \event@min}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\event@max{%
      \event@cur > \event@max ? \event@cur : \event@max}%
  }%
}{%
  \t@event@toka=\expandafter{\event@tmpa\\}%
  \edef\event@tmpa{%
    \noexpand\matrix (a) [row sep=5pt] {%
      \noexpand \draw[->] (\event@min pt - 1cm, 0) -- (\event@max pt + 1cm, 0);%
      \the\t@event@toka%
    };%
  }%
  \event@tmpa%
  \endgroup%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,x=0.5cm]
  \newcommand*{\mylabshift}{0.25}
  \begin{timeline}
    \event*{0}{0}
    \event*{1}{1}
    \event*[*]{2.5}{\cdots}
    \event*{4}{\tau}
    \event*[5]{5+\mylabshift}{\tau+1}
    \event*[*]{7.25}{\cdots}
    \event*{9}{t}
    \event*[10]{10+\mylabshift}{t+1}
    \event*[*]{12.25}{\cdots}
    \event*{14}{t+h}
    \event*[19]{19-3*\mylabshift}{T-h}
    \event*[20]{20+5*\mylabshift}{T-h+1}
    \event*{25}{T}
  \end{timeline}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Original Answer

Use `anchor= base` to align the text.
[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,x=0.5cm]
  \newcommand*{\mylabshift}{0.25}
  \draw[->] (-1,0) -- (27,0) node[anchor=base, yshift=-7mm]{Time};
  \foreach \x in {0,1, 4,5, 9,10, 14, 19,20, 25}
  \draw(\x, 1.2mm) -- (\x, -1.2mm);
  \foreach \x/\what in {
    0/0, 1/1, 2.5/\dots, 4/\tau, 5+\mylabshift/\tau+1, 7.25/\dots, 9/t,
    10+\mylabshift/t+1, 12.25/\dots, 14/t+h, 19-3*\mylabshift/T-h,
    20+5*\mylabshift/T-h+1, 25/T
  }
    \node[anchor=base] at (\x,-7mm) {$\what$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: ... great, thanks. With `\dots` replaced by `\cdots` it looks good.